# IIS 8 Publish - eliminate hang time when application gets updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, teamcity, msdeploy

What are the best practises to limit (or best, eliminate) hang time when publishing changes to a single-server IIS 8 ASP.NET MVC application?

Now, we are deploying our changes via MSBuild.exe trough TeamCity. Once the app is deployed, it hangs for a little less than a minute doing its startup things (building NHibernate proxy assemblies, changing db schema, building ioc container etc.).

Is there a way for us to setup that the "old" process keeps handling requests until the new one is fully ready (and not just deployed) ?

EDIT:

Our startup code is launched via the

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(..), "..")]
```

attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what version of IIS you are using, but if you are using version 8.0 then you might want to take a look at the Application Initialization feature: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

You'll want to set your application pool start mode to AlwaysRunning and then set preloadEnabled to true. Setting preloadEnabled to true tells IIS 8.0 to send a "fake" request to your application when the associated application pool starts up, whilst this won't eliminate the startup compilation, it will mean your application is available sooner than it was previously. You can also set IIS to display an alternative page whilst compilation is occurring, if you don't want your users hanging on...

Comment: Thank you. We are using IIS 8. Instead of an alternative page, is there a way to keep using the old process? Displaying a page does not help me, we need people to keep working with the system...

Comment: There isn't a way to do what you'd like to do, so I'd suggest you take advantage of Application Initialization, which will warm up the app as soon as you've deployed. You might also like to take a look at this blog post which talks about optimising asp.net startup time: http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/12/01/Slash-your-ASPNET-compileload-time.aspx